# Display while alternating values

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have an array contains the players names, I want to display with each question a player's name following the array's order, for example arrNames['mark', 'john', 'jay'], I want to display along with question one mark, question 2 john, etc. With each iteration I want the name to change to its following in the array.

This is what I'm trying but I only get the last value in the array, how can I fix it ?

```
const names = [];
var counter = 0;
const limit = 4 * localStorage.getItem('playersNum');

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if(counter < limit) {
    // Display player's name and ask question
    for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        const playerName = document.getElementById('card-title');
        playerName.innerText = names[i];
        console.log(names);
    }
    const h6 = document.getElementById('h6');
    h6.innerHTML = "Question " + (counter + 1);
    nextBtn.innerHTML = "Next";
    // Randomely pick a question from the array
    randomItem = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length)];
    random = document.getElementById('questions');
    random.innerText = randomItem;
    counter++; 
  } else {
    alert('No more questions !')
  }
});
```

Comment: *I only get the last value in the array* is alittle unclear, but looking at your code `document.getElementById('card-title')` is looking for `id="card-title"` i.e a single element, so its just replacing its innertext on each iteration of the for loop.. hence why your only seeing the last replaced item as its final value

Comment: `innerText += variable`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for your response, _document.getElementById('card-title') is looking for id="card-title" i.e a single element, so its just replacing its innertext on each iteration of the for loop_ . that's exactly what I want to be doing, but with each iteration the name changes to the following one in the array

Comment: Get rid of the for loop and do `playerName.innerText = names[counter];`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
// Display player's name and ask question
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  const playerName = document.getElementById('card-title');
  playerName.innerText = names[i];
  console.log(names);
}
```

To

```
const playerName = document.getElementById('card-title');
playerName.innerText = names[counter];
```

Why, because it's looping over all names, irrespective of `counter`'s current value, hence why your only seeing the last name.

Comment: hey, thanks it worked, how can it start again when the questions are still going, for example when I have 8 questions and 3 players, when it reaches the end of the names array, it start again until there are no more questions ?

Comment: without testing you could prob use modulo `names[counter % questions.length];`, then counter will always be within questions.length regardless of counter value